# При прокрутке страницы фон становится белым

Tags: css, css3, reactjs, background

Проблема заключается в следующем:
В проекте react есть layout в этом layout`е есть container, который задает боковые границы контенту. 
Далее все объекты проекта рендерятся именно в нем.

Таким образом единственный нормальный способ задать фон, это задать его самому layout, т.к. он растянут на всю видимую ширину страницы.

```
.layout
  position: relative
  height: 100vh
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #ffffff, #f8f9ff, #eff3ff, #e4eeff, #d7e9ff, #d7e9ff, #d7e9ff, #d7e9ff, #e4eeff, #eff3ff, #f8f9ff, #ffffff)
```

и все норм, но при появлении большого кол-ва контента на странице появляется скрол. И при прокрутке вниз, появляются белые места без фона. Что с этим делать?

свойство background-attachment: fixed не работает

единственное что приходит на ум, сделать объект на одном уровне с layout с position fixed. Но как по мне, это не очень красивый способ...

Answer (score 1):

Единицы измерения `vw`, `vh` - Viewport Height, Viewport Width - это процентная величина от общей ширины и высоты области просмотра.

Длина в `%` рассчитывается относительно ширины текущего контекста (**контейнера**), а длина `vw`, `vh` — относительно общей ширины, высоты области просмотра **браузера**.

Например, если высота окна браузера равна `900px`, то `1vh` будет равен `9px`!

У Вас для `.layout` задана высота `100vh`, а высота контента не вмещается в эту высоту.

Как вариант, можно использовать все же проценты:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
  height: 100%;
}

.layout {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #ffffff, #f8f9ff, #eff3ff, #e4eeff, #d7e9ff, #d7e9ff, #d7e9ff, #d7e9ff, #e4eeff, #eff3ff, #f8f9ff, #ffffff);
}


main {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="layout">
    
  </div>
</main>
```

Либо задать минимальную высоту:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.layout {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #ffffff, #f8f9ff, #eff3ff, #e4eeff, #d7e9ff, #d7e9ff, #d7e9ff, #d7e9ff, #e4eeff, #eff3ff, #f8f9ff, #ffffff);
}


.inner {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="inner">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```